# How can I install all video codes into vlc player?

Tags: video, vlc

I can not play all DVD's on my DVD ROM.  I was told that I need to install codes for VLC.  You should be able to do this via the Terminal,  I am not shore of the command string to use.  `sudo apt-get install vlc codes` is not working.  Do you perhaps know ?

Answer (score 1):

Start with just vlc if you haven't and see if it brings everything it needs:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

If not, try also installing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4 libdvdnav4 libdvd-pkg
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need libdvdcss which is usually not available by default on Debian (and Debian-like) distributions.

http://www.videolan.org/developers/libdvdcss.html

Comment: Thanx a lot.  I'll see to it tomorrow,  but thanx in Advance !!!